# Impresso utilizando IReports

Tags: java, ireport

Boa noite,

Preciso desenvolver um impresso para o padrão 80x30mm que seria para impressora térmica.

Havia pensado em criar um modelo no ireports e no momento da impressão chamar o modelo, porém estou tendo dificuldades em dimensionar o modelo dentro do ireports.

Existe um lugar onde posso informar os parâmetros de tamanho do modelo que desejo?

Ou se existe uma outra forma, mais fácil ou melhor para que seja desenhado este tipo de impresso.

Comment: Você gostaria de definir o tamanho do papel?

Comment: Sim, eu não encontrei um local onde defino o tamanho do papel.

Comment: "No iReport no menu Format tem uma opção chamada Page Format, nesta opção vc pode usar um tamanho padrão, por exemplo do A0 até A7, ou ter um tamanho customizado selecionando a opção Custom e definindo o tamanho do papel."
Tirei de: http://www.guj.com.br/java/232082-ireport---tamanho-de-papel-diferente-de-a4-resolvido

Comment: OK, a opção é que eu precisava muito obrigado. Utilizando o ireports, seria uma opção usual para imitir impressos  para recibos?

Comment: Sim, mas por experiência própria em alguns casos achei muito mais fácil utilizar a biblioteca itext para fazer alguns relatórios. Recomendo que leia sobre quando tiver oportunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme respondido nos comentários:

> No iReport no menu Format tem uma opção chamada Page Format, nesta
>   opção vc pode usar um tamanho padrão, por exemplo do A0 até A7, ou ter
>   um tamanho customizado selecionando a opção Custom e definindo o
>   tamanho do papel.

Fonte: http://www.guj.com.br/java/232082-ireport---tamanho-de-papel-diferente-de-a4-resolvido